# Convert string's array in time and decrement hour in PHP

Tags: php

I have this little script. I would like to convert the array `$ora[$i]` in time so I can manage the hour (decrement), the format is '`h:i A`' `es.: 1:00 PM`, but with this command I cannot convert `echo date('h:i A', strtotime($ora[$i]));`. There is an error.
Thank you very much.

```
$output=file_get_contents($uri);
$ora = array();
if (
  preg_match_all ('/<td colspan="1"><div class="tbl_EPG_TimesColumn.*?">(.*?)<\/div><\/td>/s', $output, $posts, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)
) {
  $ciao=$posts[0];
  $ora = array_values(array_unique($ciao));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  echo date('h:i A', strtotime($ora[$i])); 
}
```

EDIT: this is the printf of $ora --> 12:00 AM  2:00 AM 3:00 AM 3:30 AM
I would like to change the hour for example from 12:00 AM to 11:00 AM and the same for the other hours

Comment: Show us the value of $ora using print_r

Comment: I think you should be using `$posts[1]` because `$posts[0]` contains the whole matches, not the memory captures; also `$count` doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: `strtotime('12:00 AM')` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to define $count, try this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ora); $i++) {
  echo date('h:i A', strtotime($ora[$i])); 
}
```

edit: I tested it myself and it seems fine?

```
$ora = array('12:00 AM', '01:00 PM');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ora); $i++) {
  echo date('h:i A', strtotime($ora[$i])); 
}
```

output:

```
12:00 AM
01:00 PM
```

Comment: yes i did but it doesnt work, the values are not right

Comment: could you explain in details why It is not working? I tried it myself it seems to be working perfectly. show us what is you output/error in the question then maybe we can help. We cann't help with a simple "it is not right" comment.